# Select month, year and quantity and show months with zero entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(MONTHNAME(date), 3) AS month,
YEAR(date) AS year,
COUNT(id) AS quantity
FROM
budgets
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

which returns me this:

```
|month|year|quantity|
---------------------
|  Jan|2018|      10|
|  Mar|2018|       2|
|  May|2018|       5|
```

I need to show months even if `COUNT(id)` not exist
like this:

```
|month|year|quantity|
---------------------
|  Jan|2018|      10|
|  Feb|2018|       0|
|  Mar|2018|       2|
|  Apr|2018|       0|
|  May|2018|       5|
```

Anyone knows a way to do that?

**UPDATE**

According to D-Shih answer code, query returns this:

```
|month|year|quantity|
---------------------
|  Jan|2018|      10|
|  Feb|null|       0|
|  Mar|2018|       2|
|  Apr|null|       0|
|  May|2018|       5|
```

And if I add a register with different year it will show only one row with name 2017 like:

```
|month|year|quantity|
---------------------
|  Jan|2018|      10|
|  Feb|null|       0|
|  Mar|2018|       2|
|  Apr|null|       0|
|  May|2018|       5|
|  May|2017|       2|
```

it must show

```
|month|year|quantity|
---------------------
|  Jan|2018|      10|
|  Feb|2018|       0|
|  Mar|2018|       2|
|  Apr|2018|       0|
|  May|2018|       5|
|  Jan|2017|       0|
|  Feb|2017|       0|
|  Mar|2017|       0|
|  Apr|2017|       0|
|  May|2017|       2|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make a calendar table and `OUTER JOIN` base on the calendar table

```
SELECT t1.month,
       y.year AS year,
       COUNT(t2.id) 
FROM (
    SELECT 'Jan' month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Feb' month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mar' month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Apr' month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May' month
) t1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) FROM budgets) y  
LEFT JOIN budgets t2 on t1.month = LEFT(MONTHNAME(t2.date), 3) 
   AND y.year = YEAR(t2.date)
GROUP BY t1.month, y.year
```

---

Here is a sample for you.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE budgets (
   `month` varchar(5),
   `year` int,
   quantity int
);


insert into budgets values ('Jan',2018,10);
insert into budgets values ('Mar',2018,2);
insert into budgets values ('May',2018,5);
insert into budgets values ('May',2017,2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
| month | year | quantity |
| ----- | ---- | -------- |
| Jan   | 2018 | 10       |
| Mar   | 2018 | 2        |
| May   | 2018 | 5        |
| May   | 2017 | 2        |
| Jan   | 2017 | 0        |
| Feb   | 2018 | 0        |
| Feb   | 2017 | 0        |
| Mar   | 2017 | 0        |
| Apr   | 2018 | 0        |
| Apr   | 2017 | 0        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k1d1fwUomNUi5LhnFpxoZE/0)

Comment: Ok, it worked, but if I had a value that is another year it also counts. There is a possibility count different years?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: it's 5.7.14, I`ll post edit answer with screen what is going on with

Comment: I`ve updated the question. Can you analize it?

Comment: @AlexandreHansen OK wait a secnod.

Comment: @AlexandreHansen You can try it.

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much sir!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale this, I think this should work. Not very sure about how efficient it would be though:

```
SELECT a.month AS month, a.year AS year, COALESCE(b.quantity,0) AS quantity
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(date) AS month, YEAR(date) AS year
   FROM
   budgets
) a
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, YEAR(date) AS year,
   COUNT(id) AS quantity
   FROM
   budgets
   GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
) b
ON a.month = b.month AND a.year = b.year
```

Comment: Hi Vishnu, the code returns same values from normal select!